# HandlebarsJS - How to split up data

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have this Backbone App whehre I have an API which gives me information about Bands Album and its relevant tracks from a MySQL database. When I do the classic `{{#each this}}`-thing, I get all data listed in one big `<ol>`-and you cannot see which Album the tracks belong to. What I want to achieve is a structure like this:

```
 <album>
    <tracks>

 <album>
    <tracks>

 ...etc
```

So right now, my code looks like this:

```
<div>
{{#each this}}
<div class="pc33">        
    <img src="{{cover_image}}" />
</div>
<section>
    <h2>{{album_title}}</h2>
</section>
<section class="tl pc66 floatright">
    <div>
        <ol>
            {{#each this}}
            <li>{{track_title}}<span>{{track_duration}}</span></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ol>
    </div>
</section>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

But that doesnt work - each track gets the album cover and starts with 1. track title...

My console spits out the JSON

```
0: {pro_id:507, album_title:I Care 4 U, track_title:…}
1: {pro_id:507, album_title:I Care 4 U, track_title:…}
2: {pro_id:507, album_title:I Care 4 U, track_title:…}
3: {pro_id:507, album_title:I Care 4 U, track_title:…}
4: {pro_id:508, album_title:Miss You, album_genre:R & B, cover_image:…}
5: {pro_id:509, album_title:One In A Million, track_title:…}
6: {pro_id:509, album_title:One In A Million, track_title:…}
7: {pro_id:509, album_title:One In A Million, track_title:…}
8: {pro_id:509, album_title:One In A Million, track_title:…}
9: {pro_id:509, album_title:One In A Million, track_title:…}
10: {pro_id:509, album_title:One In A Million, track_title:…}
11: {pro_id:510, album_title:Aaliyah, track_title:…}
12: {pro_id:510, album_title:Aaliyah, track_title:…}
13: {pro_id:510, album_title:Aaliyah, track_title:…}
14: {pro_id:510, album_title:Aaliyah, track_title:…}
15: {pro_id:510, album_title:Aaliyah, track_title:…}
16: {pro_id:510, album_title:Aaliyah, track_title:…}
```

So again, I want to have the structure like mentioned above. How can I do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a sample of your data.

Comment: @Jack I updated my qestion, check it out!

Comment: Your problem is that your JSON structure doesn't match what you are trying to do in your template. What you want is a structure where each album is one object that contains an array of tracks, something like `{pro_id:510, album_title:"Aaliyah", tracks: [...], ..}`. IF you have control over the API then you can change the way you output the data there, if not you can modify it client side in JavaScript (you might want to have a look at underscore's [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function).

Comment: @Jack thanks! you're right, I managed to solve it with lodash's groupBy function, as you suggested!